# Update of Bluemix run times or services. Will they always be backward compatible?

Tags: paas, ibm-cloud

I've been playing with IBM Bluemix (liking it a lot so far) and we are considering to use it for production. What I'm not totally clear on is what happens when runtime environments or services get updated. I assume this happens quite frequently.

Will the new version be always backward compatible? If so, is this guaranteed somewhere in the terms of service?

What I am trying to avoid is to put production code on the platform and then having to update it constantly (or having it break) due to runtime or service updates.

Does anyone have any experience? Have past updates always been backward compatible?

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't believe there is a guarantee that the buildpacks will always be backwards compatible, you will always be able to select the previous buildpack version.

Try running a 'cf buildpacks' command and have a look at the buildpack names and version info encoded therein and think you'll see what I mean.

Comment: 'cf buildpacks' seems to tell me that there is a previous buildpack version for java and node.js available, which would solve the issue for (at least) these two languages.

How about services though? 'cf marketplace' lists only one version for each service. I then tried 'cf marketplace -s cloudantNoSQLDB' to get more details on a specific service, but couldn't find anything on a previous version that I might be able to bind.

Comment: Services do not work the same way buildpacks do. Only the current version of a service can be provisioned.

Comment: Yes, understood. Getting back to my original question, that means that service APIs need to be backward compatible. Correct? If not, an updated service API might break my app.

Comment: That is a distinct possibility however most services take design choices that allow for multiple versions of their APIs to be in play at once. For example '/v1/api/xxxxxxx' and '/v2/api/xxxxxx'

Answer (score 0):

When buildpacks are updated they won't be used for your application until you restage it, so you have some control over when to pick up the updates as well. This gives you a chance to test it on non-production versions of the app.